# jquery autocomplete trigger dropdown on input:focus

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the popular JQuery Autocomplete plugin below.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Currently if you type a phrase the drop down appears but when you click away it hides. This is fine. However the only way to bring the dropdown back is to either click in the input field and type further characters or press keydown.

Any ideas on how to trigger the dropdown of results when the user clicks in the input field? I've tried to trigger the focus event for the input field but that doesn't work. I somehow need to manually call the autocomplete dropdown event when the input field is focused. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/CNYCS/

Cool; so all you need to do is `bind` focus event with the autocomplete, rest `autocomplete will take over from there as you can see in the demo.

Helpful Link: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-bind-focus-input-to-trigger-autocomplete **&** http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#method-search

Hope this helps,

Rest code is in jsfiddle.

**code**

```
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength:0
    }).bind('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("search"); } );
```

Comment: Sweet! Exactly what I need! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

There is no obvious way to do so according to doc. But you can try with `focus` (or `click` or `keyup`) event on the `autocomplete` enabled `textbox`:

```
$('#autocomplete').trigger("keyup");
```

or

```
$('#autocomplete').trigger("focus");
```

or

```
$('#autocomplete').trigger("click");
```

As **@Tats_innit** mentioned the code, after that you need to just add the line

```
$('#tags').trigger("focus"); // as @Tats_innit's solution bind focus
                             // so you need to trigger focus
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CNWj8/1/)**

Comment: ++1 again man `:)` glad these days I am not jinx-ing solution with yours :P diff demo below for OP anyhow +!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the code given above. In my case availableTags were loading from server values. Hence I wanted to open popup only if the value was blank - this saves an unnecessary trigger for server to load tags again on focus.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength:0
    }).bind('focus', function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I know it kinda defeats the purpose, but is it possible to open the dropdown with all options even if there is content in the text field? Or does anyone have a suggestion for a different plugin that would do this? I basically want a free text input with a pre-defined list showing up on focus, not filtered.

Comment: If you remove the following condition, this code will get your job done.             if ($(this).val().length == 0) {