# How to show default suggestions in Jquery autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want that whenever a user clicks on the form input, a default list of options should appear e.g. [Refer practo](http://www.practo.com.)

Click on Specialities, doctors clinic etc. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please write what have you tried.

Comment: Do you use ajax call to fill auto complete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery autocomplete trigger dropdown on input:focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168446/jquery-autocomplete-trigger-dropdown-on-inputfocus)

Comment: 1. apply a list to source = ['doctor,clinic',..]  2.  on search change you need to change source as per new data retried fron ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#tags" )
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    }).on('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("instance").search("a"); } );
```

Will work instead of "autocomplete("search")"
Full Code is Below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" )
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    }).on('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("instance").search("a"); } );

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Anshu: </label>
  <input id="tags";>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CNYCS/):

```
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength:0
    }).on('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("search"); } );
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168511/4613398