# How to trigger .catcomplete to automatically show dropdown list of results upon focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I see it is available using the .autocomplete("search") method for autocomplete, but this does not work for catcomplete

References: 
[jquery autocomplete trigger dropdown on input:focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168446/jquery-autocomplete-trigger-dropdown-on-inputfocus/11168511#11168511)
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Comment: Can you forward some code? I had same issue and I solved that, I don't know you have exactly same issue or not. in my issue I tried to show full list after `dblclick` on `input` that used catcomplete and autocomplete.